# Inverse Fourier transform (in frequency) of a rectangular pulse

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

This is my first question on here so I'm new to the formatting and all so please be indulgent :)

I have an exam question where I am given a function H(f) that is a rectangular pulse between -fc and fc (where fc is a given frequency) of amplitude 1 and I need to calculate it's inverse Fourier transform. I've looked around online and could only find vague answers and not in the frequency domain.

Alternatively, if some of you want to think a little more, I have a given signal x(t) which is also a rectangular pulse between -d and d of amplitude A, I have it's frequency Fourier transform which is

```
X(f) = 2*A*d*sinc(2*pi*f*d)
```

I then have to convert x(t) into xp(t) where xp(t) is the periodic version of x(t) of period T and Xp(f) is the fourier transform of xp(t).

Assuming I now have xp(t), Xp(f) and H(f), the full question is:

We set xp(t) at the input of h(t), determine the range of frequencies fc such that the output signal y(t) is a sine function. To solve this I must either calculate a convolution of xp(t) and h(t) to get y(t) as a sine function or multiply Xp(f) and H(f), find Y(f) such that its inverse Fourier transform is a sine function.

I know that the fourier transform of a sine function is:

```
(1/2j)*[dirac(f-f0)-dirac(f+f0)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I didn't notice all the mistakes...

Comment: You are not allowed to post three questions in a single answer. Obviously, your homework-like question has three parts and you are trying to have it solved for you here, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I see @msm, I should explain that this isn't homework but revision for an upcoming exam which is why there are many parts. I would love to be able to make the question more acceptable, I'm just not sure which parts are crucial to finding the right path to the answer...

Comment: Look at Rules 201, 202 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional. I'm not sure what is vague there.

Comment: What do you mean by set xp(t) at the input of h(t)? Where did h(t) come from?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean do the convolution of xp(t) and h(t)

Comment: Fine, but what is h(t)?

Comment: My wild guess using standard tables is that h(t) (inverse Fourier transform of H(f)) is: h(t) = 2*fc*sinc(fc*t) but I'm not sure...

Comment: What is this an exam in?

Comment: Signal processing and fourier transforms

Comment: $x_p$ is a $T$ periodic function and using the Fourier transform can be written as $x_p(t)=\sum_k {X_p}(k) e^{i {2k \pi \over T} t}$. The response for each $t \mapsto e^{i {2k \pi \over T} t}$ can be easily computed using $H({k \over T})$. Figure out $f_c$ so only one frequency (and its negative, of course) get through.